# What is the type of precision in the prior distribution over user's and item's latent factors in PMF?

Tags: machine-learning, graphical-model, stan

I am trying to implement the pmf model in stan. [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3208-probabilistic-matrix-factorization.pdf) 
In this model, there are two prior normal distribution over the latent factors of users and items:

$U_i$ ~ $normal(0,\sigma^2I$)

And it is said that the $I$ is a indicator matrix where $I_{ij}$ equals 1 if user $i$ has rated $j$, otherwise 0. I wonder what is the type of $\sigma^2$? single value, or vector,matrix? I think it is just a single value. But if so, the product, $\sigma^2I$ should be a matrix? But the stan can not handle the case where the precision is a matrix, how can I transform it to vector or single value? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This does not make sense, because a covariance matrix must be symmetric but $\sigma^2 I$ will generally be asymmetric. It looks like the paper uses some confusing notation: It defines $I_{ij}$ as you describe, but it uses a boldface $\mathbf I$ to represent the identity matrix, not the matrix $I_{ij}$.

Comment: @BrentKerby is correct that this $I$ refers to the identity matrix. Also, you might be interested in [my Stan implementation of BPMF](https://github.com/AutonlabCMU/active-matrix-factorization/blob/master/stan-bpmf/bpmf.stan) from a few years ago; it does some tricks to speed things up, though it's possible more recent changes in Stan might need updates.

Comment: In retrospect, that code might not be ideal – for example, depending on the density of observations, it's probably faster to multiply $U V^T$ than to dot rows of them together separately. There also might be something smarter to do with the linear algebra, and/or Stan updated functions that would help....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a multivariate normal distribution then you can do this in Stan using multi_normal, e.g. if $U_i$ is a vector of length $K$ you can do

```
U_i ~ multi_normal(rep_vector(0,K), Sigma)
```

where Sigma is the covariance matrix.

However $\Sigma = \sigma^2 I$ means you don't have any non-zero covariance terms, so you can just use univariate normals

```
U_i ~ normal(0, sigma)
```

which will give each element in $U_i$ a normal distribution with mean zero and standard deviation $\sigma$ (Stan parameterizes the univariate normal in terms of the standard deviation and not the variance).